# Tomar una lista con números en Python y cambiar sus valores sin repeticiones

Tags: python

Tengo un array o lista en Python con 9 números (`lista=[1,1,1,1,3,5,6,7,9]`). Necesito un código que tome esos números, los recorra y que cuando encuentre uno repetido me genere aleatoriamente un nuevo número para remplazarlo; la idea es que al final se arroje un nuevo array o lista con nueve números sin repetir.

Escribí este código tratando de controlar el valor del bucle con la variable *j* con el fin que no se salga del mismo hasta que no encuentre un valor aleatorio adecuado. ¿Qué me estará fallando?

```
import random

lista=[1,1,1,1,3,5,6,7,9]
      #0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8

for i in range(len(lista)):
    aux=i
    for j in range(1, len(lista)):
        
        if lista[j]==lista[i]:
            aleatorio=random.randint(0,9)
            if aleatorio not in lista:
                lista[i]=aleatorio
            else:
                aux=i
                j=j-1
```

Comment: ¿Debemos conservar en la lista los NO repetidos? Es decir, ¿cambiamos únicamente los repetidos?

Answer (score 0):

Prueba así:

```
import random

lista=[1,1,1,1,3,5,6,7,9]
n_lista=[]

for i in lista:
    if i not in n_lista:
        n_lista.append(i)
    else:
        j=random.randint(0,9)
        while j in n_lista:
            j=random.randint(0,9)
        n_lista.append(j)

print(n_lista)
```

En cambio, si quieres conservar los números que no se repiten y modificar únicamente los repetidos, el algoritmo sería:

```
import random

lista=[1,1,1,1,3,5,6,7,9]

for i in range(len(lista)):
    l_aux=lista.copy()
    del l_aux[i]
    if lista[i] in l_aux:
        j=random.randint(0,9)
        while j in l_aux:
            j=random.randint(0,9)
        lista[i]=j

print(lista)
```

Comment: En mi opinion, una explicacion de lo como funcionan dichos algoritmos estaria genial c:

Comment: Por supuesto, lee el código y, cualquier duda que te surja, déjamela en los comentarios :) Es fácil de entender, no recuerdo haber hecho ninguna pirueta extraña

Answer (score 0):

El problema en tu código es que pretendes que `aleatorio=random.randint(0,9)` saque un número que no se encuentre en la lista en un solo intento, algo demasiado optimista, y, al no siempre suceder, entonces el valor no se reemplaza y por eso es que a veces ves valores repetidos en la salida.
Lo que debes hacer es recorrer cada elemento, como el `for` más externo y luego con un `while` ir testeando números hasta que encuentre uno que no se repita.

---

En esta versión propongo recorrer la lista de derecha a izquierda, si el índice actual `i` es diferente a otro indice `lista.index(lista(i))` significa que hay otro valor igual al principio de la lista. Entonces se reemplaza el último por un número aleatorio generado. Tiene la ventaja que no cambia el orden de la primera aparición de los elementos en la lista original

```py
import random

lista=[1,1,1,1,3,5,6,7,9]
largo = len(lista)
for i in reversed(range(len(lista))):
    if i != lista.index(lista[i]): # <-- Si hay un elemento repetido
        while True:
            aleatorio = random.randint(0, largo)
            if aleatorio not in lista:
                lista[i] = aleatorio
                break
print(lista)
```

Salida: `[1, 4, 0, 8, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9]`

---

Otra versión, con menor costo de iteraciones. Será mucho más eficiente con listas largas, ya que es exponencialmente más complicado para el CPU hacer coincidir un valor aleatorio específico cuando las probabilidades son más grandes.

Por ejemplo, una lista de **500** elementos y solo falta generar un **258**. Puede tardar una o miles de iteraciones para que salga ese **258**.

En este caso se selecciona al azar de una lista de elementos consecutivos, `lista2`, y que se van eliminando a medida que se van testeando.
Al igual que el anterior, tampoco cambia la primera aparición de un elemento:

```py
import random

lista=[1,1,1,1,3,5,6,7,9]

lista2 = list(range(len(lista)))
for i in reversed(range(len(lista))):
    if i != lista.index(lista[i]):
        while True:
            aleatorio = random.choice(lista2)
            lista2.remove(aleatorio) # <-- Se elimina el elemento
            if aleatorio not in lista:
                lista[i] = aleatorio
                break
print(lista)
```